# remove same product from two widget

Tags: product, product-attribute, catalog, products, widget

In our magento 2 store.
We have 3 sections

1. Featured Products
2. Trending Products
3. Top Picks

in this section the products are showing, but problem is product can have all these 3 attributes selected.
i want if ABC product is selected all these attributes and its showing in featured product then it wont appear in trending and top pick section. Currently it is showing both.

can any one please help me with this problem?

Comment: You have to modify the collection code of every section, so it not include product which added into another collection.